# add value to dictionary key as list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

Is it possible I can treat my dictionary's key's values as list?

How to append new value to that list?

```
#my dictionary
mydic = {}

#my key
username = "praveen"

#my value
user_accessKey = "tmp1"
user_accessKey2 = "tmp2"
```

How to construct a dictionary like this, with my key and value?

```
print (mydic)
{"praveen":["tmp1","tmp2"]}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you know how to write a dict and a list? What's stopping you from doing that? Do you know how to access a dict value? In other words, what have you already tried, and where are you stuck? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Use [collections.defaultdict(list)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple dictionary assignment

```py
mydic[username] = [user_accessKey, user_accessKey2]
```

To append values (thanks @wjandrea for the suggestion):

```py
mydic.setdefault(username, []).append(new_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to do it directly:

```
mydic = {username: [user_accessKey, user_accessKy2]}
```